Is the law of excluded middle provable (no dependencies)?
I'm currently self studying logic using Halvorson's book "How Logic Works" and am stuck trying to show that (P or not P) is provable using no dependencies. Namely that, ⊢ (P or not P) using only conditional proof, double negation, Modus Ponens and Tollens, Conjunction intro and elimination and disjunction intro. Any help for this proof would be greatly appreciated. Here is my solution but I have no idea if it is correct. Picture of my work

The classical logic assumes it : If $A$ is a false statement , then "not A" must be true. In mathematics , this is often obviously justified , for example either there infinite many twin primes or only finite many , there is no third possibility.

Excluded middle follows from (in fact is equivalent to) double negation elimination (for all $A$, $\neg \neg A \to A$). Proving this is a good exercise.

It can help to show how you are using the logical modus.

@NaïmFavier would the proof in the picture I just uploaded be a correct derivation?

Over intuitionistic logic, adding excluded middle is equivalent to adding double negation elimination. It is easy to verify $(P ∨ ¬P) ⇒ (¬¬P ⇒ P)$. In the other direction, you cannot prove $P ∨ ¬P$ from $¬¬P ⇒ P$, but you can prove $P ∨ ¬P$ by applying double negation elimination on a proposition different than $P$. Namely, you prove $¬¬(P ∨ ¬P)$, and double negation elimination allows you to conclude $P ∨ ¬P$. Now, to prove $¬¬(P ∨ ¬P)$, assume $¬(P ∨ ¬P)$, this entails $¬P ∧ ¬¬P$ (exercise), which yields a contradiction.
